# MongoDB what are the default user and password?

Tags: mongodb

I am using the same connection string on local and production.
When the connection string is `mongodb://localhost/mydb`

What is the username and password?
Is it secure to keep it this way?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

By default mongodb has no enabled access control, so there is no default user or password.

To enable access control, use either the command line option `--auth` or security.authorization configuration file setting.

You can use the following procedure or refer to [Enabling Auth](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-scram-client-authentication/) in the MongoDB docs.

## Procedure

1. Start MongoDB without access control.

   ```
    mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
   ```
2. Connect to the instance.

   ```
    mongosh --port 27017
   ```
3. Create the user administrator.

   ```
    use admin
    db.createUser(
      {
        user: "myUserAdmin",
        pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
        roles: [ 
          { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
          { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } 
        ]
      }
    )
   ```
4. Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control.

   ```
    mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
   ```
5. Authenticate as the user administrator.

   ```
    mongosh --port 27017 --authenticationDatabase "admin"\
        -u "myUserAdmin" -p
   ```

Comment: If user is created with role userAdminAnyDatabase, then will be impossible to create any database. Therefore roles section should be: roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]

Comment: Please link the [original post from MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)

Comment: if you want to find the dbpath use: grep dbPath /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: @georgeos I've tried that, and it is ok, can create database without any problem. as natcho mentioned, same way proposed in MongoDB manual .

Comment: If need to delete user and create again with different role as mentioned by @georgeos use `db.dropUser("myUserAdmin")`

Comment: Recent versions of Mongo use `mongosh` as the command, not `mongo`, eg: `mongosh --port 27017`

Answer (score 29):

In addition with what @Camilo Silva already mentioned, if you want to give free access to create databases, read, write databases, etc, but you don't want to create a root role, you can change the 3rd step with the following:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, 
             { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, 
             { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

If you have already created the user, you can update the user as follows:

First log on:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" \
  --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

The add permissions:

```
use admin
db.grantRolesToUser(
   "myUserAdmin",
   [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, 
     { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, 
     { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
)
```

Comment: To create a Replica Set, and administer a cluster, it is need to add role "clusterAdmin"

Comment: upvoting because of the --authenticationDatabase parameter. Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

For MongoDB earlier than 2.6, the command to add a root user is `addUser` (e.g.)

```
db.addUser({user:'admin',pwd:'<password>',roles:["root"]})
```

Comment: Till version 2.6 you had `db.addUser`. Starting 2.6 and in current version 3.4.x you can create an user with `db.CreateUser`.

Comment: `db.createUser` ;) (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to previously provided answers, one option is to follow the 'localhost exception' approach to create the first user if your db is already started with access control (`--auth` switch). In order to do that, you need to have localhost access to the server and then run:

```
mongo
use admin
db.createUser(
 {
     user: "user_name",
     pwd: "user_pass",
     roles: [
           { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
           { role: "readWriteAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
           { role: "dbAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }
        ]
 })
```

As stated in MongoDB documentation:

> *The localhost exception allows you to enable access control and then create the first user in the system. With the localhost exception, after you enable access control, connect to the localhost interface and create the first user in the admin database. The first user must have privileges to create other users, such as a user with the userAdmin or userAdminAnyDatabase role. Connections using the localhost exception only have access to create the first user on the admin database.*

Here is the link to that [section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception) of the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Go to mongo in your instance

```
    mongo

    use admin

    db.createUser({user:"Username", pwd:"Password", roles:[{role:"root", db:"admin"}]})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
mongod --bind_ip_all --auth
```

use this command after modifying the .conf file:

```
 network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,mongodb_server_ip
```