# See / change local username and password for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Ive downloaded a project using MongoDB and im having trouble getting set up. From the terminal where ive run `mongod` I see this error:

```
2017-05-26T14:51:22.908+0800 I ACCESS   [conn21] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for user on wesbostest from client 127.0.0.1:51653 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user user@wesbostest
```

From my `npm start` terminal mongoose logs out this error: `Authentication failed.`

My environment file has this line:

```
DATABASE=mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/wesbostest
```

Ive got MongoDB Compass installed. It successfully connects with these settings:

```
Hostname: localhost
Port: 27017
Authentication: None
SSL: Off
SSH Tunnel: Off
```

So I think the `user:pass` part of the environment file is wrong? How can I see what local username and password are and/or set them if no authentication is set up?

Comment: Login with a username and password you actually know then. If you don't have another account that can access then you are out of luck. Not much point in adding authentication if there is an easy back door to come in through.

Comment: See this [How can I enter Mongo as a superuser or reset users?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62976/how-can-i-enter-mongo-as-a-superuser-or-reset-users) posted on the site where you should be asking administration questions.

Comment: Ive just installed mongoDB locally and I don't know any username and passwords. Part of my question was how to see / change them.

Comment: If you just installed then there is no username and password, so simply remove them from your application connection string. If you have migrated data from somewhere and authentication is needed then follow the process you were pointed to. So you are either misunderstanding the usage, or you have an administration question that is not about programming and belongs on another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by setting a username and password for MongoDB:

[MongoDB what are the default user and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921414/mongodb-what-are-the-default-user-and-password)

## Procedure

1. Start MongoDB without access control.

   ```
   mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
   ```
2. Connect to the instance.

   ```
   mongo --port 27017
   ```
3. Create the user administrator.

   ```
   use admin
   db.createUser(
     {
       user: "myUserAdmin",
       pwd: "abc123",
       roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
     }
   )
   ```
4. Re-start the MongoDB instance with access control.

   ```
   mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db1
   ```
5. Authenticate as the user administrator.

   ```
   mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" \
     --authenticationDatabase "admin"
   ```